# Displaying Calculations On different html pages, from a javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, calculation

I'm a total noob at this, just learning HTML and JavaScript. I am making a step by step how to draw a Sri Chakra, there are calculations you have to make for each step, and I want them user to just input a number, after which all of the formulas appear, as in the answers. the calcualtions are simple like, x/4=a, x/5=b, x/8=c, x*1.15=d
Then on different pages when they get to that step I would like for a or b or c or d to show up. When they firs calculate it, I want the numbers to appear in the form as the answer. 
This is what I have for one page.
My JS is calculator.js

```
function calculate(){
var mainradius=prompt ("What is the radius of the Main Circle?","");
var a=mainradius/4;
localStorage.setItem("fourth","a");
document.write(fourth + "<br />");
var b=mainradius/5;
var b= localStorage.setItem ("1/5","b");
var c=mainradius/8;
var c= localStorage.setItem ("1/8","c");
var d=mainradius*1.15;
var e=mainradius*1.25;
var f=mainradius*1.3;
var g=mainradius*1.35;
var h=mainradius*1.4;
var i=mainradius*1.45;
var j=mainradius*1.5;
}

the page that runs the calculator page 2 is
<html>
<head>
<title> Material and Calculator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js">
</script>
<input type="number" onclick="calculate()" value="0">
<h1> Material and Calculator </h1>
<h3> Input the length of the Main Radius <br/>

<h3><form oninput="x.value=parseInt(mainradius.value)/4, y.value=parseInt(mainradius.value)/5, z.value=parseInt(mainradius.value)/8
, g.value=parseInt(mainradius.value)*1.15, h.value=parseInt(mainradius.value)*1.25, i.value=parseInt(mainradius.value)*1.3, j.value=parseInt(mainradius.value)*1.35, 
k.value=parseInt(mainradius.value)*1.4,l.value=parseInt(mainradius.value)*1.45, m.value=parseInt(mainradius.value)*1.5">
  <input type="number" id="mainradius" value="0">
  =<output name="x" for="mainradius"></output> ( 1/4th ) <br>
  =<output name="y" for="mainradius"></output> ( 1/5th ) <br>
  =<output name="z" for="mainradius"></output> ( 1/8th ) <br>
  =<output name="g" for="mainradius"></output> ( *1.15 ) <br>
  =<output name="h" for="mainradius"></output> ( *1.25 ) <br>
  =<output name="i" for="mainradius"></output> ( *1.3 )  <br>
  =<output name="j" for="mainradius"></output> ( *1.35 ) <br>
  =<output name="k" for="mainradius"></output> ( *1.4 )  <br>
  =<output name="l" for="mainradius"></output> ( *1.45 ) <br>
  =<output name="m" for="mainradius"></output> ( *1.5 )  <br>
  </form>
<p> Reccomended using 4 or 5 </p>
</fieldset>
</form></h3>
<h1><a href="index.html"> Back </a>
<a href="3.html"> Next </a></h1>
</body>
</html>

and the page I want like the one fourth to come up in is page 5
<html>
<head>
<title> Step 3 a.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Step 3a </h1>
<h2> Now Mark your line with 9 Marks, Labeled A-I </h2>
<h2> You will split the top half of the radius into 4 Sections </h2>
<h3> Label the Top of the Line A </h3>
<h3> 1/4th the radius from A Label B </h3>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calculator.js">
var fourth =parseInt(localStorage.getItem("fourth"));
document.write(fourth + "<br />");
</script>
<output type="number" value="fourth"> is 1/4th the radius </output>

<h3> 1/4th the radius from B Label C </h3>
<h3> 1/5th the radius from C Label D </h3>
<h2><img class="pic3" src="../gifs/4Marks.png" /> </h2>
<h2><img class="pic2" src="../gifs/3.gif"/> </h2>
<h1><a href="4.html"> Back </a>
<a href="6.html"> Next </a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have you tagged `java` if you're "just learning html and javascript"?

Comment: Please don't tag this with unrelated tags such as 'Java.' You'll get plenty of support by just tagging 'javascript.'

Comment: I believe the reason is, and I quote, `"I'm a total noob at this"`

Comment: @zero01alpha - lol

Comment: Yep, literally my first post lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest, and probably the most efficient, would be to store your calculated values in [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), and then read them back when needed.

```
// write
localStorage.setItem("valueA", "22");

// read
var valA = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("valueA"));
```

Comment: What does the 22 do?

Comment: I think i am understanding it, basically I don't actually use Javascript for this, its all html5.

Comment: But how do I get the value thats stored to show up ?

Comment: @KopiThiyagalingam `calculator.js` is javascript, so you use that. The `22` is just a random value that get stored, in its place you use your values. After storing a value on page page you can bring it back on another, which is the simplest way of doing what you ask

Comment: So I'm trying this but it doesn't display the number in the html

Comment: @KopiThiyagalingam Can you show how you used it, both storing and restoring the value?, and I'll have a look when I get back from work

Comment: @KopiThiyagalingam Add it to your question och give me a link to a fiddle or similar

Comment: I added it to my question thanks :) not sure what a fiddle is

Comment: @KopiThiyagalingam Use `localStorage.setItem("fourth",a);` ... note, no quotes `"` on `a` as it is a variable

Comment: Okay looks like it stores it properly, but how do I get it to display later on? when I try document.write, it tends to erase everything else on the page

Comment: @KopiThiyagalingam That is a completely different question, so best way is to accept mine, if it solved your main question and post a new regarding `document.write`